# Make pacman move randomly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pacman

I am creating a pacman game using noobtuts' tutorial. https://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-pacman-game  However I want to make pacman to be able move on its own. My idea is to make it choose a random direction to move, and it will head into that direction if it is a valid move. How should I do it? Appreciate any answers!

This is noobtuts' code that moves pacman with user input.

```html
Vector2 dest = Vector2.zero;

    void Start()
    {
        dest = transform.position;
        disabled = false;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Move closer to Destination
        Vector2 p = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, dest, speed);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(p);

        // Check for Input if not moving
        if ((Vector2)transform.position == dest && !disabled)
        {
            if (DirectionEmulator.direction == "up" && valid(Vector2.up))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.up;
            if (DirectionEmulator.direction == "right" && valid(Vector2.right))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.right;
            if (DirectionEmulator.direction == "down" && valid(-Vector2.up))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.up;
            if (DirectionEmulator.direction == "left" && valid(-Vector2.right))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.right;
        }

        // Animation Parameters
        Vector2 dir = dest - (Vector2)transform.position;
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("DirX", dir.x);
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("DirY", dir.y);
    }

    bool valid(Vector2 dir)
    {
        // Cast Line from 'next to Pac-Man' to 'Pac-Man'
        Vector2 pos = transform.position;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast(pos + dir, pos);
        return (hit.collider == GetComponent<Collider2D>());
    }
```

Comment: Use the `Random` class and replace calls to the user input with calls to random calls.

Comment: I tried doing exactly that(and logically it should work), but then pacman wouldn't move. Is there possibly something I misunderstand about how Vector2 works?

Comment: When do you want your Pacman to change direction? If you do it on every Update, it would probably just result in Pacman rapidly switching directions each frame and getting nowhere. It would make more sense to only change direction when he reaches an intersection.

Comment: @BenM I didn't think that this can make Pacman stuck... perhaps a random valid direction should be picked first, then when the direction is no longer valid the direction will change?

Comment: @Naomikho - That would probably work, but it might not be as random as you'd like, since he'd never change direction at 4-way intersections (or 3-way intersections where he can go straight ahead). But it's probably fairly easy to implement so it would be worth doing to make sure you're on the right track before doing anything more complicated.

Comment: @Naomikho - If you do want to go further and make him change directions at intersections, here's a simple idea for intersection detection: you'll know he's at an intersection (or a corner) if the set of valid directions changes. So in each update, you could test all four directions and store them in a list, and if that list ever changes, you'll know to pick a different direction.

Comment: @BenM Thank you so much! I managed to make it work; of course, there's still more I can work on but I'm on the right track again! I never thought that generating a random direction each frame will just end up making pacman not move at all :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work as of now, but I believe much more can be improved. Please provide any input if you have any solutions!

```
   private string move;
    Vector2 dest = Vector2.zero;
    

    void Start()
    {
        dest = transform.position;
        disabled = false;
        move = "right";
    }

    void FixedUpdate() //use this to decide movement
    {
        // Move closer to Destination
        Vector2 p = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, dest, speed);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(p);

        // determine next destination
        if ((Vector2)transform.position == dest && !disabled)
        {
            //check valid direction
            if (move == "up" && valid(Vector2.up))
            {
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.up;
            }

            if (move == "right" && valid(Vector2.right))
            {
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.right;
            }
                
            if (move == "down" && valid(-Vector2.up))
            {
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.up;
            }
                
            if (move == "left" && valid(-Vector2.right))
            {
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.right;
            }



            //if not valid, change direction
            // choose random valid direction
            System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
            int rand = rnd.Next(1, 4);

            if (rand == 1 && valid(Vector2.up))
            {
                move = "up";
            }
            else if (rand == 2 && valid(Vector2.right))
            {
                move = "right";
            }
            else if (rand == 3 && valid(-Vector2.up))
            {
                move = "down";
            }
            else if (rand == 4 && valid(-Vector2.right))
            {
                move = "left";
            }
        }

        // Animation Parameters
        Vector2 dir = dest - (Vector2)transform.position;
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("DirX", dir.x);
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("DirY", dir.y);
    }

    bool valid(Vector2 dir)
    {
        // Cast Line from 'next to Pac-Man' to 'Pac-Man'
        Vector2 pos = transform.position;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast(pos + dir, pos);
        return (hit.collider == GetComponent<Collider2D>());
    }
```